usepackage loads .sty file from texmf-dist instead of texmfhome
I have customs versions of packages tabularray.sty and piton.sty in my local texmf :
$ kpsewhich -a tabularray.sty
/home/yann/texmf/tex/latex/chato/tabularray.sty
/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tabularray/tabularray.sty

$ kpsewhich -a piton.sty
/home/yann/texmf/tex/latex/chato/piton.sty
/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/piton/piton.sty

However, \usepackage loads piton.sty from texmf-dist.
I wonder why that is, considering is correctly loads tabularray.sty from my localtexmf.
Is this because piton.sty is under lualatex ? Is this a luatex bug ? A texlive bug ?
tlmgr conf gives the following, which seems in order to me :
=========================== kpathsea variables ===========================
ENCFONTS=.:{{}/home/yann/.texlive2024/texmf-config,/home/yann/.texlive2024/texmf-var,/home/yann/texmf,!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-local,!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-config,!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-var,!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist}/fonts/enc//
SYSTEXMF=/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-var:/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-local:/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist
TEXCONFIG={{}/home/yann/.texlive2024/texmf-config,/home/yann/.texlive2024/texmf-var,/home/yann/texmf,!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-local,!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-config,!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-var,!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist}/dvips//
TEXFONTMAPS=.:{{}/home/yann/.texlive2024/texmf-config,/home/yann/.texlive2024/texmf-var,/home/yann/texmf,!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-local,!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-config,!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-var,!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist}/fonts/map/{kpsewhich,pdftex,dvips,}//
TEXMF={{}/home/yann/.texlive2024/texmf-config,/home/yann/.texlive2024/texmf-var,/home/yann/texmf,!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-local,!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-config,!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-var,!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist}
TEXMFCONFIG=/home/yann/.texlive2024/texmf-config
TEXMFDBS={!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-local,!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-config,!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-var,!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist}
TEXMFDIST=/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist
TEXMFHOME=/home/yann/texmf
TEXMFLOCAL=/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-local
TEXMFMAIN=/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist
TEXMFSYSCONFIG=/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-config
TEXMFSYSVAR=/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-var
TEXMFVAR=/home/yann/.texlive2024/texmf-var
TEXPSHEADERS=.:{{}/home/yann/.texlive2024/texmf-config,/home/yann/.texlive2024/texmf-var,/home/yann/texmf,!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-local,!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-config,!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-var,!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist}/{dvips,fonts/{enc,type1,type42,type3}}//
VARTEXFONTS=/home/yann/.texlive2024/texmf-var/fonts
WEB2C={{}/home/yann/.texlive2024/texmf-config,/home/yann/.texlive2024/texmf-var,/home/yann/texmf,!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-local,!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-config,!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-var,!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist}/web2c
==== kpathsea variables from environment only (ok if no output here) ====

Below is the log for
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{piton, tabularray}
\begin{document}
thing
\end{document}

This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024)  (format=lualatex 2024.8.15)  26 AUG 2024 12:52
 system commands enabled.
**texstudio_dYkeHD.tex
(./texstudio_dYkeHD.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-07-20>
Lua module: luaotfload 2024-02-14 3.28 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-var/luatex-
cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2023-12-28.lua" from kpse-res
olved path "/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-2023-1
2-28.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 3.134
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 2
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-var/luatex-
cache/generic/names".
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_truetype_file'.
Removing  `luaotfload.glyph_stream' from `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.glyphstream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_vlist' in `post_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.cleanup_files' in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_unicode' in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyphinfo' in `glyph_info'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload.letterspace_done = 3
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' in `luaotfload.patch_font_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `tracingstacklevels' in `input_level_string'. (/opt/yann/texlive/texm
f-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from /opt/yann/texlive/texmf-var/lu
atex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc.gz)
\c@part=\count192
\c@section=\count193
\c@subsection=\count194
\c@subsubsection=\count195
\c@paragraph=\count196
\c@subparagraph=\count197
\c@figure=\count198
\c@table=\count199
\abovecaptionskip=\skip49
\belowcaptionskip=\skip50
\bibindent=\dimen140
) (/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/piton/piton.sty (/opt/yann/texlive
/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty (/opt/yann/texlive/texmf
-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2024-07-20 L3 programming layer (loader) 
(/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def
File: l3backend-luatex.def 2024-05-08 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count266
Inserting `l3color' in `luaotfload.parse_color'.
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box52
))
Package: l3keys2e 2024-05-08 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
Package: piton 2024/08/12 v3.1a Highlight informatic listings with LPEG on LuaL
aTeX
(/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text
(/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks17
\ex@=\dimen141
)) (/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty
Package: luatexbase 2015/10/04 v1.3 luatexbase interface to LuaTeX 
(/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty
Package: ctablestack 2015/10/01 v1.0 Catcode table stable support
\@catcodetablestackcnt=\count267
)
\CatcodeTableOther=\catcodetable14
\CatcodeTableExpl=\catcodetable15
) (/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luacode/luacode.sty
Package: luacode 2012/01/23 v1.2a lua-in-tex helpers (mpg)
(/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
(/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
))
\luacode@lines=\toks18
\luacode@table@soft=\catcodetable16
)
\l__piton_nb_lines_int=\count268
\l__piton_nb_non_empty_lines_int=\count269
\g__piton_line_int=\count270
\l__piton_splittable_int=\count271
\g__piton_env_int=\count272
\l__piton_width_dim=\dimen142
\l__piton_line_width_dim=\dimen143
\g__piton_tmp_width_dim=\dimen144
\l__piton_left_margin_dim=\dimen145
\l__piton_numbers_sep_dim=\dimen146
\l__piton_tab_size_int=\count273
\l__piton_gobble_int=\count274
\g__piton_indentation_int=\count275
\l__piton_number_lines_start_int=\count276
\g__piton_visual_line_int=\count277
) (/home/yann/texmf/tex/latex/chato/tabularray.sty
Package: tabularray 2024-02-16 v2024A Typeset tabulars and arrays with LaTeX3
\l__tblr_a_int=\count278
\l__tblr_c_int=\count279
\l__tblr_r_int=\count280
\l__tblr_d_dim=\dimen147
\l__tblr_h_dim=\dimen148
\l__tblr_o_dim=\dimen149
\l__tblr_p_dim=\dimen150
\l__tblr_q_dim=\dimen151
\l__tblr_r_dim=\dimen152
\l__tblr_s_dim=\dimen153
\l__tblr_t_dim=\dimen154
\l__tblr_v_dim=\dimen155
\l__tblr_w_dim=\dimen156
\l__tblr_a_box=\box53
\l__tblr_b_box=\box54
\l__tblr_c_box=\box55
\l__tblr_d_box=\box56
\g__tblr_table_count_int=\count281
\c@rownum=\count282
\c@colnum=\count283
\c@rowcount=\count284
\c@colcount=\count285
\abovesep=\dimen157
\belowsep=\dimen158
\leftsep=\dimen159
\rightsep=\dimen160
\g_tblr_level_int=\count286
\g__tblr_data_row_key_count_int=\count287
\g__tblr_data_column_key_count_int=\count288
\g__tblr_data_cell_key_count_int=\count289
\g__tblr_array_int=\count290
\l__tblr_key_count_int=\count291
\l__tblr_key_quotient_int=\count292
\l__tblr_key_quotient_two_int=\count293
\l__tblr_key_remainder_int=\count294
\g__tblr_data_str_value_count_int=\count295
\rulewidth=\dimen161
\l__tblr_strut_dp_dim=\dimen162
\l__tblr_strut_ht_dim=\dimen163
\g__tblr_cell_wd_dim=\dimen164
\g__tblr_cell_ht_dim=\dimen165
\g__tblr_cell_head_dim=\dimen166
\g__tblr_cell_foot_dim=\dimen167
\l__column_target_dim=\dimen168
\l__tblr_caption_box=\box57
\l__tblr_caption_left_box=\box58
\l__tblr_row_head_box=\box59
\l__tblr_row_foot_box=\box60
\l__tblr_row_head_foot_dim=\dimen169
\tablewidth=\dimen170
\l__tblr_table_firsthead_box=\box61
\l__tblr_table_middlehead_box=\box62
\l__tblr_table_lasthead_box=\box63
\l__tblr_table_firstfoot_box=\box64
\l__tblr_table_middlefoot_box=\box65
\l__tblr_table_lastfoot_box=\box66
\l__tblr_remain_height_dim=\dimen171
\l__tblr_long_from_int=\count296
\l__tblr_long_to_int=\count297
\l__tblr_curr_i_int=\count298
\l__tblr_prev_i_int=\count299
\l__tblr_table_page_int=\count300
\l__tblr_table_head_box=\box67
\l__tblr_table_foot_box=\box68
\l__tblr_table_head_foot_dim=\dimen172
\l__tblr_table_head_body_foot_dim=\dimen173
\l__tblr_table_box=\box69
\l__tblr_table_hlines_box=\box70
\l__tblr_hline_box=\box71
\l__tblr_row_box=\box72
\l__tblr_col_o_wd_dim=\dimen174
\l__tblr_col_b_wd_dim=\dimen175
\l__tblr_hline_leftskip_dim=\dimen176
\l__tblr_hline_rightskip_dim=\dimen177
\l__tblr_row_ht_dim=\dimen178
\l__tblr_row_dp_dim=\dimen179
\l__tblr_row_abovesep_dim=\dimen180
\l__tblr_row_belowsep_dim=\dimen181
\l__tblr_row_vlines_box=\box73
\l__tblr_vline_box=\box74
\l__tblr_cell_box=\box75
\l__row_upper_dim=\dimen182
\l__row_lower_dim=\dimen183
\l__row_vpace_dim=\dimen184
\l__tblr_vline_aboveskip_dim=\dimen185
\l__tblr_vline_belowskip_dim=\dimen186
\l__tblr_cell_wd_dim=\dimen187
\l__tblr_cell_ht_dim=\dimen188
\l__tblr_diag_box=\box76
) (/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2023/11/15 v3.01 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
(/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 274.
(/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def
File: luatex.def 2024/04/13 v1.2e Graphics/color driver for luatex
) (/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1350.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1354.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
) (./_build/texstudio_dYkeHD.aux)
\openout1 = texstudio_dYkeHD.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 5
.
(/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2023/04/13 v2.5m Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
(/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ninecolors/ninecolors.sty
Package: ninecolors 2022-02-13 v2022D Select colors with proper color contrast
(/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2024-05-08 L3 Experimental document command parser
)) (/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count301
\scratchdimen=\dimen189
\scratchbox=\box77
\nofMPsegments=\count302
\nofMParguments=\count303
\everyMPshowfont=\toks19
\MPscratchCnt=\count304
\MPscratchDim=\dimen190
\MPnumerator=\count305
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count306
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks20
)

[1

{/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./_build/tex
studio_dYkeHD.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-07-20>
 ***********
)

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 4591 strings out of 475910
 100000,1977958 words of node,token memory allocated
 406 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 48 glue_spec,
 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:32,3:4,4:10,5:23,6:2,7:38,9:24
 27218 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 15 fonts using 716007 bytes
 79i,5n,89p,206b,126s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
</home/yann/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf>
Output written on texstudio_dYkeHD.pdf (1 page, 2652 bytes).

PDF statistics: 15 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 8 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)


I have no problems here. I created piton.sty in a path similar to yours and just loads \ERROR to make it react if it was loaded. kpsewich and lualatex finds it just fine from another folder. Have you messed with some of your configuration? Fx TEXMFINPUTS (or what its name is).

Thanks for the suggestion, but apparently not ; I will update the question to reflect that.

What does kpsewhich --var-value TEXINPUTS say?

.:{{}/home/yann/.texlive2024/texmf-config,/home/yann/.texlive2024/texmf-var,/home/yann/texmf,!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-local,!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-config,!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-var,!!/opt/yann/texlive/texmf-dist}/tex/{kpsewhich,generic,latex,}//

Mine look sowhat similar. Might be an idea to write the tex-live mailing list, see https://tug.org/mailman/listinfo

You can show the correct search path with
kpsewhich -progname lualatex -show-path .tex

that will show you that the luatex directories are searched before the latex directories, and thus the piton.sty from the texmf-dist tree is found first.
Always provide the -progname argument to kpsewhich to get correct answers.
Best fix is to move your local piton.sty into the same tree as in texmf-dist, so under lualatex.

any idea which this is different here? Becasue as I mentioned in my comment that is not what I set using a similar setup.
